# UICollectionViewCell drop shadow and round corners not working

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, dropshadow, cornerradius

I have the following code:

```
class ProductCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var productImageView: UIImageView!

    func setup(productModel: ProductModel)
    {
        productImageView.image = productModel.image
    }

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        productImageView.layer.cornerRadius = layer.cornerRadius
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add drop shadow to the `collectionviewcell` and also make its corners round, however, nothing happens - please see attached image.

[image: Collection view cell]

What am I missing here? Why are the corners not round and the shadow is not also goes down a bit?

By the way - `ClipToBounds` on the cell is set to `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `clipsToBounds = true` on your `productImageView` so it clips the image.